# RabbitMQ server on RHEL7 resets SSL connection

Tags: openssl, rabbitmq, rhel7

I've been trying to connect to RabbitMQ server on RHEL7 which listens to 5671 port for SSL connections.

```
RabbitMQ server's SSL listener has been configured like this:
[
  {rabbit, [
     {ssl_listeners, [5671]},
     {ssl_options, [{cacertfile,"/etc/pki/tls/certs/samqp.dcu.ie.chain"},
                {certfile,"/etc/pki/tls/certs/samqp.dcu.ie.crt"},
                {keyfile,"/etc/pki/tls/private/samqp.dcu.ie.key"},
                {verify,verify_peer},
                {fail_if_no_peer_cert,false}]}
   ]}
]
```

On a client side I get this exception message:

The client machine is Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

The client is a Moodle custom plugin using 'videlalvaro/php-amqplib' library to communicate with server.

Here are actual paths and file names for my self signed certificates created according to docs on: https://www.rabbitmq.com/ssl.html

```
$sslOptions = array(
            'cafile' => '/home/duro/testca/cacert.pem',
            'local_cert' => '/home/duro/client/key-cert.pem',
            'peer_name'=>'samqp.dcu.ie',
            'verify_peer_name' => true
            );
```

PHP apparently has a requirement to use certificate and key concatenated to one file, hence the 'key-cert.pem'.

This is how I connect from client, including actual url:

```
$connection = new AMQPSSLConnection('samqp.dcu.ie.crt', 5671, 'rMQUsername', 'rMQPasswd', '/', $sslOptions)
```

On the client side I get this exception message:

```
"stream_socket_client(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages: error:14090086:SSL routines:ssl3_get_server_certificate:certificate verify failed"
```

On the server side, looking to /var/log/rabbitmq/rabbit@sphinx.log, I see this error:

```
=ERROR REPORT==== 3-Mar-2016::14:08:26 ===
SSL: certify: ssl_alert.erl:93:Fatal error: unknown ca
```

So, how to make this connection work?

Comment: Please post the exact URL you are using to connect to the server, and post the output of `openssl s_client -connect <hostname>:<port> -tls1 -servername <hostname> | openssl x509 -text -noout`. Do so by adding it to your question by clicking *Edit* (and don't post it as a comment). Otherwise, we can't reproduce it and there's not enough information to help troubleshoot it.

Comment: I supplied the actual URL in $connection instantiation code. I also posted the command output, and updated the file names and paths to real ones.

Comment: Thanks @Djuro. It was easy to diagnose with the information. I wish everyone provided it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ... error:14090086:SSL routines:ssl3_get_server_certificate:certificate verify failed"

You are connecting to the server with the name ***`sphinx.dcu.ie`***:

```
$connection = new AMQPSSLConnection('sphinx.dcu.ie', 5671, ...)
```

However, the hostname in the certificate is ***`samqp.dcu.ie`***:

```
X509v3 Subject Alternative Name: 
    DNS:samqp.dcu.ie
```

You need to do one of two things. First, make the RabbitMQ request against the server named in the certificate. Or second, get a new certificate issued with the DNS name you want to use.

You can place as many DNS names as you like in the *Subject Alternate Name (SAN)*. I often fill them up with debug and testing names, like ***`localhost`***, ***`localhost.localdomain`*** and ***`127.0.0.1`***.

---

***EDIT***: For this issue:

> ... and server's log now says:
>
> ```
> =ERROR REPORT==== 3-Mar-2016::09:52:41 ===
> SSL: certify: ssl_handshake.erl:1490:Fatal error: unknown ca
> ```

You need to go back to the information for [Revision 9](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/35721046/9) or so of your question and this information:

```
depth=2 C = US, O = DigiCert Inc, OU = www.digicert.com, CN = DigiCert  High Assurance EV Root CA
verify return:1
depth=1 C = NL, ST = Noord-Holland, L = Amsterdam, O = TERENA, CN =   TERENA SSL High Assurance CA 3
verify return:1
depth=0 businessCategory = Government Entity, jurisdictionC = IE,   serialNumber = Government Entity, street = Glasnevin, street = Dublin City   University, postalCode = IE, C = IE, ST = Ireland, L = Dublin, O = Dublin  City University, OU = ISS, CN = samqp.dcu.ie
verify return:1
```

You ***don't*** need the `ca-cert.pem` file which includes hundred of CAs and most of which are wrong. You only need the one CA that's right, and its the once called ***DigiCert High Assurance EV Root CA***. You also need the intermediate one called ***TERENA SSL High Assurance CA 3***

***DigiCert High Assurance EV Root CA*** *certificate*

You can download ***DigiCert High Assurance EV Root CA*** from [DigiCert Trusted Root Authority Certificates](https://www.digicert.com/digicert-root-certificates.htm). It has the following attributes:

- Serial number: 02:AC:5C:26:6A:0B:40:9B:8F:0B:79:F2:AE:46:25:77
- Thumbprint: 5FB7EE0633E259DBAD0C4C9AE6D38F1A61C7DC25

When you download it, its in DER format. You need to convert it to PEM format with:

```
$ openssl x509 -inform der -in DigiCertHighAssuranceEVRootCA.crt \
    -outform PEM -out DigiCertHighAssuranceEVRootCA.pem
```

Then:

```
$ cat DigiCertHighAssuranceEVRootCA.pem 
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIDxTCCAq2gAwIBAgIQAqxcJmoLQJuPC3nyrkYldzANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQUFADBs
...
vEsXCS+0yx5DaMkHJ8HSXPfqIbloEpw8nL+e/IBcm2PN7EeqJSdnoDfzAIJ9VNep
+OkuE6N36B9K
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

***TERENA SSL High Assurance CA 3*** *certificate*

Now you need to do the same thing with ***TERENA SSL High Assurance CA 3***. I believe you can find it at [TERENA SSL High Assurance CA Root Certificates](https://pki.cesnet.cz/en/ch-tcs-ev-ssl-ca-3-crt-crl.html). Its the one with the attributes:

- Serial number 0b:5c:34:35:67:5b:24:67:c0:d7:32:37:f9:0d:5f:94
- Fingerprint SHA1 A7:8A:AB:DE:7F:5B:77:15:40:D3:33:B5:05:87:4C:82:04:AA:D2:06

***MY-CACERT.pem***

Now that you have the CAs you need for pathbuilding, perform the following:

```
$ cat DigiCertHighAssuranceEVRootCA.pem > my-cacert.pem
$ cat TERENA_SSL_High_Assurance_CA_3.pem >> my-cacert.pem
$ echo "" >> my-cacert.pem
```

Then:

```
$ cat my-cacert.pem 
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIDxTCCAq2gAwIBAgIQAqxcJmoLQJuPC3nyrkYldzANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQUFADBs
...
vEsXCS+0yx5DaMkHJ8HSXPfqIbloEpw8nL+e/IBcm2PN7EeqJSdnoDfzAIJ9VNep
+OkuE6N36B9K
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIE4DCCA8igAwIBAgIQC1w0NWdbJGfA1zI3+Q1flDANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQsFADBs
...
dnnqz5SeAs6cbSm551qG7Dj8+6f/8e33oqLC5Ldnbt0Ou6PjtZ4O02dN9cnicemR
1B0/YQ==
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

Finally, use ***`my-cacert.pem`***.

---

You should be able to test things using OpenSSL's ***`s_client`***. But I can't seem to connect from the outside world:

```
$ openssl s_client -connect sphinx.dcu.ie:5671 -tls1 \
    -servername sphinx.dcu.ie -CAfile my-cacert.pem
```

If you can connect, then you should get a ***`Verify Ok (0)`*** (if I recall correctly).

Comment: Updated again, if that is what you mean.

Comment: I solved the problem by removing 'cafile' and 'local_cert' from $sslOptions, I kept 'peer_name' and 'verify_peer_name'. Messages go and log entry looks good. Can you modify your answer like that or add a new one, I'll accept it. Does that make sense?

Comment: @DjuroMandinic - I tried to address the additional problems you are having. I can't connect to `sphinx.dcu.ie:5671` from the outside world, so I don't know its its completely correct.

Comment: It is not supposed to accept outside connections for the time being. I can confirm that the server accepts connections over SSL listener on 5671 port and messages are being received. Log file says this:     `=INFO REPORT==== 3-Mar-2016::14:48:14 ===
accepting AMQP connection <0.20455.1> (136.206.4.190:23456 -> 136.206.1.29:5671)`   

`=INFO REPORT==== 3-Mar-2016::14:48:14 ===
closing AMQP connection <0.20455.1> (136.206.4.190:23456 -> 136.206.1.29:5671)`

Answer (score 0):

I had have the same problem while connecting to RabbitMQ server from PHP client. Error was

```
"stream_socket_client(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages: error:14090086:SSL routines:ssl3_get_server_certificate:certificate verify failed"
```

I debugged it by following below series of steps

**Making sure client and server are handshaking using the provided certificate files.**

In one terminal run below command to start server on 8443 port.

```
openssl s_server -accept 8443 -cert /etc/rabbitmq/server/cert.pem -key /etc/rabbitmq/server/key.pem -CAfile  /etc/rabbitmq/testca/cacert.pem
```

And, in another terminal run below command to make connection.

```
openssl s_client -connect YOUR_SERVER:8443 -key /rabbitmq/client/key.pem -CAfile /rabbitmq/client/key-cert.pem
```

If the client is able to connect and doesn't return back to prompt due to timeout, your connection is successful. Try using your certificates/keys until you make the connection successfully.

> Note: It is assumed the key-cert is concatenated file.

```
# cd /etc/rabbitmq/client
# cat key.pem cert.pem > key-cert.pem
```

**SSL Options in PHP client**

I passed below PHP array as `$ssl_options` parameter.

```
$ssl_options =  [
                        'cafile' => '/rabbitmq/testca/cacert.pem',
                        'local_cert' => '/rabbitmq/client/key-cert.pem',
                        'verify_peer' => false,
                        'verify_peer_name' => false,
            ];
```

My RabbitMQ configurations are according to the [docs of VMWare](https://docs.vmware.com/en/vCloud-Availability-for-vCloud-Director/2.0/com.vmware.vcavcd.install.config.doc/GUID-81B2D9FC-CCE0-45FD-9560-09EE5790FD15.html).